# Who are these DC villians from Justice League: Crisis on Two Earths?

Tags: dc, character-identification, justice-league-crisis-on-two-earths

I’m watching [Justice League: Crisis on Two Earths](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1494772/) and I'm having trouble identifying these two members of the [Crime Syndicate](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Crime_Syndicate).

They appear in the battle around 15 minutes into the movie.

Does anyone recognise them?

> *This villain could shoot energy / lightning from his hands:*

[image]

> *This villain has similar powers to Green Lantern but didn't use any sort of ring that I could see:*

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first is [Breakdance](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Breakdance_%28Crisis_on_Two_Earths%29)

> Breakdance is a parallel version of the superhero, Vibe. He is able to
>   focus and generate his power through dance moves, hence his codename.
>   He is one of the Crime Syndicate's Made Men, and is a lieutenant of
>   the Martian, J'edd J'arkus. However, after J'arkus' death, most of his
>   Made Men were absorbed by Owlman. He quickly countered a lack of
>   managerial talent needed to succeed J'arkus and they needed to be
>   associated with a family head immediately. Ultraman consented and
>   allowed Owlman to keep them for the time being.

The second one is [Aurora](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Aurora_%28Crisis_on_Two_Earths%29)

> Aurora is a parallel version of Halo. Owlman empowered her with an
>   aurora of energy of several colors: red for heat, orange for force
>   blasts, yellow for light, green for stasis beam, blue for distortion
>   effect, indigo for tractor beam, and violet for all powers to be used
>   at once. She became a second lieutenant of Owlman. On a mission to
>   find the Quantum Trigger, Aurora fought against Green Lantern who
>   posed a legitimate challenge to her powers. Green Lantern formed a
>   boxing glove construct and slammed Aurora into a wall, knocking her
>   unconscious.

Comment: +1 from me. I thought Aurora was just a generic Star Sapphire member.